# How to share token between Firebase and server?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Node.js app uses Firebase products as well as a server running in App Engine.
So when a user is signed in, he should be able to authenticate on both platforms. I used [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for this.

In server, I called [`admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) and sent that token to client.
In client, I used [`firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) and signed in. All good.

I also read regarding the token [`exp` field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library)

> The time, in seconds since the UNIX epoch, at which the token expires. ... But once you sign a user in using signInWithCustomToken(), they will remain signed in into the device until their session is invalidated or the user signs out.

So the Firebase handles the token refresh and all (please correct me if I'm wrong), which I don't have to worry about. Moreover, Firebase and my app uses the same keys (service account keys) to generate the token.

> Custom tokens are signed JWTs where the private key used for signing belongs to a Google service account.

So a token generated is compatible between firebase and the server.

Now, where I'm stuck is, I need token to authenticate to App Engine server. **How to get the latest (non-expired) token from firebase after doing a successful `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`?**

I could have used the `token` in `signInWithCustomToken(token)`. But this may me expired after an hour. So I thought I could depend on the firebase authentication.

Thanks.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short-lived token that Firebase SDKs auto-refresh is called an ID token, and you can get it by calling `getIDToken(false)` on the `user` object. This gives you the current ID token, so there's a chance it may expire relatively quickly - although usually not for at least 5 minutes, as the SDK requests a new ID token at that point.

You can also force the SDK to refresh the token by calling `getIDToken(true)`, which means you get a token that's valid for about an hour.

Comment: Ok. this `idToken` is not the token we used in `signInWithCustomToken(token)`, right? So if we had some additional claims in the original token, these will not be available in the `idToken` right?

Comment: The ID token contains the custom claims for that user.